# May i install caffe or caffe2 on Google Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have try `!pip install caffe` and `!pip install caffe2`, but it is not useful.

If ok, how to install caffe or caffe2? What about other framework?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You are more likely to get help if you describe what is going wrong. Do you get an error message? If so, post the error message in  the body of your question.

Comment: Here are the error: Collecting caffe
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement caffe (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for caffe

Answer (score 10):

To install Caffe with GPU support try running:

`!apt install -y caffe-cuda`

and for the CPU-only version:

`!apt install -y caffe-cpu`

Comment: @appleyuchi Can you describe what happens exactly? I currently have no problem importing caffe.io on Google Colab