# install caffe_classes in Colaboratory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, caffe, google-colaboratory

i need to run this line of code:

```
from caffe_classes import class_names
```

on this environment: Google Colaboratory (google jupyter notebook in the cloud)

I get the following error:

```
No module named caffe_classes
```

I have already tried the solution at [May i install caffe or caffe2 on Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500120/may-i-install-caffe-or-caffe2-on-google-colaboratory).
I still get the above error.

Solution i am looking for: **How to install caffe_classes in Colaboratory?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while trying to get this alexNet example to run: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/tf_alexnet/, given my solution I think you are trying the same.

The solution is easy: There is a caffe_classes.py script in the project you have to download and add to your project.